# Basic django app - app design issue

Tags: django

To learn Django, I was making a very basic app which does the following:

1. Takes a user's login (checks id password in a database).
2. If user exists and password is right, give user option to either insert,delete or update.
3. If insert, user can insert an entry into a common table.
4. Similarly for delete or update.

I was cruising through this but I just got stuck.

My Login page is `/index/`.
Option for insert/delete/update is at `/application/`.
Now next, page is displayed according to insert/delete/update at `/application/action/`

Now the problem is that after completing one insertion, I want to return to `/application` to carry on my next operation.

But if I do that, I get this error

`"Key 'userid' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"`

So the view for `/application/` is expecting the userid and password in request.POST.

How do I get around this without using external user login modules. I just want a very basic login system just to learn.

Comment: I think you can learn a lot of Django starting from this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Login systems are not basic when done correctly, you should do as @FernandoFreitasAlves says and do the django tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with user [authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) built in.  I don't think it is external as it is included in django.contrib.

If you use the built in user authentiaction and User model, you will not have to pass the `userid` to each view.  Django will automatically retrieve the logged in user from the session and make it available as a property of the `request` object.

So using built in user and authentiaction, after logging in a user, you can access that user at

`request.user`

Comment: I understand that would've been the best way to proceed with things. But now that I used simply a POST request to handle the User ID and Password in a database table, is there no way I can access that UserID and Password again in some other view without that same POST request? Something like a variable which multiple views can access.

Comment: @user1265125 you can set a session variable with the user name and password, please reconsider though, even as a learning excersise it might be better just to check out django source code.  Django authentication has so many work hours put into it, it is mature and reliable, please consider using it

Comment: Yep I definitely will look into it in my next project. With this one I just wanted to learn very basic templates and models.